# Nested react (or receive) in Scala

Tags: scala, actor

I have an intermediate remote actor (B) that is supposed forward back and forth messages from A and C ( like A <-> B <-> C ). In B's code I have something like

```
   loop {
      react {
        case msg => val A = sender
          //2) Should this be synchronous with !?
          C ! msg
          //1) What's better react or receive?
          react {
            case response => A ! response   
          }
      }
    }
```

3 Questions:

1) What's better react or receive (to nest within a react)?

2) Given that a response will be sent back, should !? be used instead of !

3) Any other recommendation for this scenario?

Thank you all!

Comment: You can pipe message using 'pipeTo', specially useful when passing message with intermediate actor.

Comment: I think pipeTo only exists in Akka, and the code above is the deprecated Scala actors model.

Answer (score 0):

For what concerns the *standard* Actor model, messages must be handled atomically (i.e. you cannot receive and process messages when you are processing another -- and that's exactly what you'd like to do here)

However, Scala Actors have a relaxed semantics, which may allow to do that.

For Question 1, you should have clear which are the differences between react and receive. Anyway, you can easily use react (as used here http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/actors-api/actors_api_guide.html)

Alternatively, you could not use nesting. After your actor has sent the request, its state should change so that that next loop cycle it will look for the reply.

You may also want to upgrade to Scala 2.10 which integrate actors from Akka; that model is more clear and easy to use.